# KineticJS: Get the mouse button, x and y from the 'click' event on a Circle

Tags: javascript, click, mouse, kineticjs

Using KineticJS, I created a Circle: using the following line:

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({...});
```

Then, I started listening to the 'click' event this way:

```
circle.on("click", function(evt) {
  // Hope to get the mouse button, x and y here...
});
```

Using the evt object above, I hope to get the mouse button that was used to click, and the X and Y of the click location. I inspected the evt object, and could not find any of these.

I did get the target node, and the event type from this 'evt' object though.

Am I missing anything? May be another argument to the click handler?

I will post a SSCCE if this information is not enough.

Any response is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest KineticJS version (5.1.0), you can get the position by accessing `evt.evt.clientX` and `evt.evt.clientY`.

Regarding the detection of which mouse button was clicked, you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery) approach with jquery for cross-browser support

Comment: Thanks! I guess evt.evt gives you the native event object. I wonder why KineticJS chose not to make the coordinates and the mouse button directly available, rather than leaving it to us to figure out.