# Open Select2 dropdown only on left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i have applied select2 on some select box, but i want to open these only on left click, not on right or middle click.

```
jQuery(".dropdown").select2({placeholder: "some text"});
```

I tried many things but nothing seems to work.
please help.

Comment: Can you show us it on a Jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following question on stack: [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

You could use a switch case to keep the select element closed depending on which mouse button was clicked, example:

```
$('.select2-selection').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            $('select').select2("close"); 
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            $('select').select2("close"); 
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could use the disable/enable options in Select2.

Comment: my problem is not to recognize mouse buttons only, i want wanted to open select2 box only on left click... i tried this already. btw thnx.

Comment: Select 2 has a close method you can use. So you could just close the select box using that method depending on which button was used? I've edited my answer to reflect this. I appreciate his doesn't directly answer your question but it may help.

Comment: thnx.. but  i used `$(select2_obj).select2("close"); ` beacuse inside `mousedown` function `this` indicating object of class `select2-selection`.. Thnk u once again.

Comment: You're welcome - it's not the most elegant solution. If it's solved the problem, could you please accept the answer. Thanks.