# Proper way to track link's click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the most exhaustive / compatible solution to track some links inside my website.

Actually, I've this code:

```
$(".article-content a").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        // Tracking code here
    });
});
```

Is there any recommandations regarding real user redirection handling ?
I think we have to firstly exclude right-click ?
And also be sure that Ctrl-Click, MouseWheel-Click, Touch events, Navigation by keyboard, etc... are properly handled to fire, for example a GA event ?

Comment: You can probably check for keycode!

Comment: Your question is too broad, there are a lot of options and possible solutions. You should specify what you need to track specifically, what you're having trouble with and show what you've tried.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Comment: In fact, i want to safely handle the real user redirection.

Answer (score 1):

make something like this

```
$('.asdfasdf').mousedown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 1:
            //Left Mouse button pressed
            break;
        case 2:
            //Middle Mouse button pressed
            break;
        case 3:
            //Right Mouse button pressed
            break;
        default:
            //asdfasdf
    }
});
```

here's some doc: [jQuery-Doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) in combination with [`.mousedown`](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/). Something like:

```
$('.article-content a').mousedown(function(event){
    var message = 'click';
    if (event.ctrlKey) message += ' ctrl';
    if (event.shiftKey) message += ' shift';

    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
           message = 'left ' + message;
           break;
        case 2:
           message = 'middle ' + message;
           break;
        case 3:
           message = 'right ' + message;
           break;
    }

    alert(message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use function with parameter to handle click

```
$(".article-content a").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
      if(e.ctrlKey) {
        //Ctrl+Click
      }
      if(e.altKey) {
        //Alt+Click
      }
      ...
    });
});
```

log `e` to console to get more information

you can listen other events for mobile: `tap, taphold, swipe, swipeleft...`

```
$(".article-content a").on("tap",function(){
  #element is tapped
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following approach.

1. Add a class to the elements you want to track:

   ```
     < a class="trackMouseClick" >I want to be tracked onclick< / a >
   ```
2. Define the event handlers for each class:

   ```
   //the actual event handler
   //here you can implement the logic for each kind of event
   function mousedownHandler(e){
       console.log('target element: ' + e.target + '\tbutton clicked: ' + e.which);
   }

   //the event binder
   //remark: the event is bound only for the elements feature the proper class
   $('.trackMouseClick').on('mousedown',function(e){
       mousedownHandler(e);
   });
   ```
3. Add as many classes and events handlers as many events you want to track:

   ```
   function mousedownHandler(e){
       console.log('target element: ' + e.target + '\tbutton clicked: ' + e.which);
   }

   function tapHandler(e){
       console.log('target element: ' + e.target);
   }


   $('.trackMouseClick').on('mousedown',function(e){
       mousedownHandler(e);
   }).on('tap',function(e){
       tapHandler(e);
   });
   ```

The main pros are:

- Modularity: you can add and remove event handlers simply adding and removing classes from your DOM elements
- Decoupling: using classes separates the DOM structure from the tracking logic you aim to implement

Comment: Ok, but not really that i want, how to be sure that i can handle all events that redirect the user on the (not right) clicked / touched / keyboard selectionned link ?