# "Open link in new tab" only from right-click

Tags: php, jquery

So, I have a div which when it is left-clicked, it brings up a popup.

However, I want to have a link to the div, so when users right-click then there is an option for "href" and can click "Open link in new tab".

Here is what I mean:

```
 <div class="show_popup">
    Shows popup for `example.com/hi`
 </div>
```

So, is there a way to add "href" which does not do any "left-click" functions (ie. does not redirect the user to another page), but when the user right clicks on it, there is an option to "open link in new tab".

I hope it makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I wondered if this was possible too and came up with the following:

**Notice:** the code will probably not work on Stackoverflow or any other service that can host code due to it running in a sandboxed environment. If you open your console you might see warnings which tell you it has blocked pop-ups. To access your console:

**Chrome**

<kbd>Ctrl / Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift / Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

**Firefox**

<kbd>Ctrl / Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift / Option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

```
$(function() {

  $('.my-element').on('click contextmenu', function(e) {

    // If the right mouse button is used 
    if (e.which === 3) {

      // Grab data-link value from <div> 
      var link = $(this).data('link');
      // Open new tab
      window.open(link, '_blank');

    }

    // Cancel default right click behavior
    return false;

  });

});
```

```css
.my-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background: tomato;
  font: bold 1em sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-element" data-link="https://www.google.com">Right click here</div>
```

Comment: This is a really interesting approach! I will give it a try =))