# How to detect right click + left click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a game

And I need to do something when the user clicks on the right mouse button, ***holds it*** and then presses the left button

How can I detect this behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask. Hint: Show code. I actually thought it was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSfiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/pd725ch6/5/**

```
var rightMouseClicked = false;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  //e.button describes the mouse button that was clicked
  // 0 is left, 1 is middle, 2 is right
  if (e.button === 2) {
    rightMouseClicked = true;
  } else if (e.button === 0) {  
    //Do something if left button was clicked and right button is still pressed
    if (rightMouseClicked) {
      console.log('hello');
      //code
    }
  }
  console.log(rightMouseClicked);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
  if (e.button === 2) {
    rightMouseClicked = false;
  }
  console.log(rightMouseClicked);
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: No particular reason, just added them at some point and forgot about them.

Comment: Just updated the answer to include a preventDefault so that the context menu does not show on right click.

Comment: Hey, its dosent work me can you take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984682/dettect-right-click-left-click-not-working ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `MouseEvent.buttons` in your event handler.

```
<element>.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
    if ((event.buttons & 3) === 3){
        //Do something here
    }
}, true);
```

It is kinda recent though, you may want to implement fallback method, recording state of mouse buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
  showCustomMenu();
  return false;     // cancel default menu
}
```

on right click every browser has default menu for refreshing page, printing, saving and lot more but you can try this one and may be it will prevent default action and add your custom. 
please write down answer if it will help you.

Comment: This event isn't supported everywhere yet and doesn't trigger on disabled elements in IE.

Answer (score 1):

for right click use `oncontextmenu` and for left just set up `click` , just disable their default behaviours if you want too,
ex:

```js
var left = 0,
  right = 0;

document.onclick = function() {
  console.log(++left);
  return false;
};

document.oncontextmenu = function() {
  console.log(++right);
  return false;
};
```

Comment: `click` event generated after user releases button. Author wants to get notification when both buttons held, i think

Answer (score 0):

Hie

check below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <input type='button' value='Click Me!!!' id='btnClick'/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnClick').mousedown(function(event){
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right mouse button pressed');
            break;
        default:
           break;
    }
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For more reference refer
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/04/find-which-mouse-button-clicked-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var hold=false;

function check(e) {
  if(e.button==2) hold=true;
  if(e.button==0 && hold) console.log('action');
}

function release(e) {
  if(e.button==2) hold=false;
}

function noContext(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
```

```css
.box { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
Hold right mouse button and press left (on sqare)
<div class="box" 
     onmousedown="check(event)" 
     onmouseup="release(event)"  
     oncontextmenu="noContext(event)"
></div>
```