# Eventlistener for right click

Tags: javascript

Is there a keycode for right click in javascript because here is what I was trying to do:

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (event.keyCode === 2) { //Right Mouse
            alert("Oh-NO!!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Comment: keycode for mouse click? that's new

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect right click + left click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973080/how-to-detect-right-click-left-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `mousedown` event rather than a `keydown` event.  This will return an `event.button` property, the value of which will tell you which button was clicked...

```
$('element').addEventListener('mousedown', clicked, false);

function clicked(e) {
    switch (e.button) {
        case 0:
          // left mouse button
          break;
        case 1:
          // middle mouse button
          break;
        default:
          // 2 === right mouse button
    }
}
```

For right- and middle-clicks you may need to [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) behaviours.

Hope that helped :)