# Mousedown event triggers only on right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

Why does:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.noUi-handle', function() {
    $(this).find('.noUi-tooltip').show();
});
```

Only trigger when I right-click `.noUi-handle` ?

I want it to trigger only on left-click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Comment: @Richard It helps but it doesn't answer the question why it only triggers on right click, I'm now using the focus & focusout events as this works even better in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `click` event instead of `mousedown`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.noUi-handle', function() {
    $(this).find('.noUi-tooltip').show();
});
```

Comment: I want to use the mousedown event because I'm dragging&dropping the `.noUi-handle`, I want it to trigger as soon as I press down the mouse button, without releasing it.