# addEventListener("mousedown.left") not working in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vue-component, mouseevent

I want to make right and left click do different things on my custom element.

In this original code. in the element file I defined some event listeners for mouse clicks:

```
container.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
container.addEventListener("contextmenu", onRightClick);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);
```

And some methods that's supposed to be called which will alter an array in the data section:

```
function startDrag(e) {
    // some code here
}

function endDrag(e) {
    // some code here
}

function onRightClick(e) {
    // some code here
}
```

The two arrays to be altered (named here `intersected` and `rightClicked` are watched, and custom events are emitted when they're altered

```
watch: {
    intersected(i) {
      this.$emit("change", i);
      console.log("emitting change");
    },
    rightClicked(i) {
      this.$emit("rightclicked", i);
      console.log("emitting rightclicked");
    }
},
```

So they work perfectly fine. However as I said, I want left and right click to do different things, and as of now right clicking triggers both `contextmenu` and `mousedown`. If I change the event listeners to

```
container.addEventListener("mousedown.left", startDrag);
container.addEventListener("contextmenu", onRightClick);

document.addEventListener("mouseup.left", endDrag);
```

left clicking would do nothing. The event `change` was never emitted. Right clicking still emits `rightclicked` as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does view somehow capture events and spit out non standard events? There is no `mousedown.left`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The `event.button` property to determine which mouse button was clicked.

Try this:

```
container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (event.button === 0) {
    startDrag(event);
  }
});

container.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the context menu from showing up
  onRightClick(event);
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  if (event.button === 0) {
    endDrag(event);
  }
});
```