# Suppressing a Browsers Default Right Click Menu - refinement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so as far as I understand it so far we have 2 approaches

Firstly some javascript which I can employ within a given script. But this switches right click off for everything.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function() {
        return false;
};
```

or in the html can code

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

but I cannot thus far find anywhere that will give me javascript or jquery solution where I can apply this to a given selector. Is this simply not possible or am I mis-understanding something.

I am finding that on a single right click my submenu appears immediately followed by the browser's default menu. The only way I have found to suppress this is setting oncontextmenu to false. Is there a more refined solution?

**Further Note to accepted answer**

Also applied successfully on a dynamic menu using delegate:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", "#existing_Flavours .field_Input_Left.flavour", function(){
        return false;   // suppress browsers default right click menu
});
```

Comment: [Don't do it](http://www.sitepoint.com/dont-disable-right-click/). It's annoying and your users will A) never visit your site again or B) bypass it via script blockers and/or manually.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click

Comment: Well I can't say that I fully understand why that should be. But I am sure you are right. But surely there must be a way to stop the default menu from appearing where right click is being used. @jbabey

Comment: @Andrew - the thing about your referenced question, is that the accepted answer is *wrong*. `contextmenu` is now supported in jQuery.

Comment: @ahren They are both right and both answers are in that question, which is the exact same question as this one.

Comment: @Andrew - the first line of the accepted answer reads: *"There is no built-in oncontextmenu event handler in jQuery"* - This is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#mySelector').on('contextmenu', function(){
  return false;
});
```

Just bind it like you would any other event...

However, if you're wanting to do this to *"protect"* content, it's very little security. It's easy to bypass.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V3sWc/

Comment: No no I don't want to protect or prevent anyone from looking at the code, I just want to stop my cancellation menu which is off the right click from being covered up by the default menu. As @jbabey is casting doubt on this am I able to assume that using it in a jquery context won't cause his script blockers from being in a huff. By the way this is exactly what I wanted to find out so many thanks. I am just going to test it.

Comment: Ok my selected elements don't display the default right click menu everywhere else on the page does. Absolutely perfect.