# how to detect right click in datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to detect if a user right-clicks a row in a table (datatables powered).

Now, the following code works fine if I use a non-ajax source:

```
oTable.$('tr').mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) { //Right Mousebutton was clicked
        window.sData = oTable.fnGetData( this );
        jQuery(this).contextMenu({ x: e.pageX + 10, y: e.pageY + 10});
    }
});
```

However, it doesn't work if I use an ajax source, so I looked around and tried:

```
jQuery('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    alert("a click!");
    if (e.which === 3) { //Right Mousebutton was clicked
        alert("actually it was a right click!");
    }
});
```

This code does detect regular clicks, but if fails to recognize a right click.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click

Comment: @Jakob: Thank you for your comment, but this approach stops working once you refresh the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexey's code works when you first load the table, but it stops working when you perform some ajax action on it. So the `.on(...)` method has to be used instead.

The code I'm currently using looks like this:

```
jQuery('#myTable tbody').on( 'mousedown', 'tr', function (e) {
     alert("mouse event detected!"); 
     if( e.button == 2 ) { 
        alert('Right mouse button!'); 
        return false; 
     } 
     return true; 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
jQuery('#myTable tbody').mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helped me figure out what I had to change -although it is not quite right- and I'm upvoting your answer because of that.