# Get calendar event in function outside of fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to access the event in a function that is not in the fullCalendar, I have a context menu that you can right click and choose DeleteEvent and it passes the target to the function:

```
var $target = $(e.target);
DeleteEvent($target);
```

When I use the debugger in chrome I can see the object I need but I can't figure out how to get to it because the numbers at the end of jquery could probably change.

So how do I write this to work everytime?

```
$target.context.offsetParent.jQuery224054666921681718872.fcSeg.event
```

I tried:

```
$target.context.offsetParent.find('fcSeg').event
$target.context.offsetParent.jQuery().fcSeg.event
$target.offsetParent().find('fcSeg').event
$target.offsetParent().closest('fcSeg').event
```

etc. Just grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to delete an event after right click, popup menu and delete so it is better if you'll keep a var named activeEvent and every time you click on event you'll assign the event object to the var and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: That isn't an option, The context menu is also in a separate function and not tied to fullCalendar in anyway except it uses a class as its selector. I need an answer on how to get the fcSeg.event. If there was an event for right click like there is for click then that would be something I would have gone with.

Comment: You can bind the right click to the event.
There is an example in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610774/click-event-in-jquery-and-right-mouse-clicking

Comment: Great that works too, I had figured out how to bind to the right click, just a different way ( through eventRender: function(event, element){element.bind('mousedown', function(e){if(e.which==3)....}} ) and then I set a global var and accessed it as you said, you should update your answer to show how that is done so others who stumble here will get their help.

Comment: also thumbs up for thinking outside the box :)