# How to call "click" on input type "file" by calling context on other element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

How I can call `"click"` event on `input type="file"` by calling `"context"` event on other element?

I am trying this code:

**HTML Markup:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <button id="trigger">Click</button>
</body>
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
window.onload = function() {
window.oncontextmenu = function(){
    return false;
};
$("#trigger").on("contextmenu", function(){
    $("#file").trigger("click");
});
```

}

But I haven't got window to choose file, when I click the right mouse button on button with `id="trigger".`

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click) thread

Comment: The event handler is triggered, but the file input won't open, changing the event from `contextmenu` to `click` makes it work, so this is clearly a security "feature" built into the browser, the same way a file input that is hidden can't be triggered for security reasons.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/1292/

Comment: The main idea is to use oncontext event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

```
  window.onload = function() {
        $("#trigger").mousedown(function(e){
            if(e.button == 2){
                $("#file").trigger("click");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

**Script:**

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $('#file').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: The main idea is to use **oncontext** event on button with id="trigger".