# jQuery divert mouse click from VNC to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, vnc

I have created one page, in which on right clicking on some button a modal appears. 
When I right click on the modal it doesn't seem to work. 
So far, what I got to know is, the mouse click is taken by the UI control which  comes underneath that modal and listening to all mouse events and that UI control VNC.

I can click on the part of the modal, which is not above that control.

Is there any way I can force modal to take all mouse events when in focus?
What I want to do is just right click and copy the text from that modal.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Ganesh

Comment: You might want to have a look into this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click

Comment: Here is bootstrap docs for modals, you porbably need to add event handler for `show.bs.modal`: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Live example (e.g. JS Fiddle) please!

Comment: Sorry, @cvrebert I just can't..
It's too much code..
Basically I have VNC control underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just called RFB's `_rfb.get_keyboard().ungrab()` method when modal is shown and was pretty done.