# Primefaces right click - backing bean method call

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, contextmenu, right-click, backing-beans

Is there a way to invoke a backing bean ajax method in JSF2/Primefaces 5.x by right clicking on an image ? There is a contextMenu component in Primefaces but it brings up a menu, which I don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/706728/3803447) jQuery code and PrimeFaces `<p:remoteCommand>` you can achieve this, here is simple code:

```
<h:form>
        <p:graphicImage id="myImage" onmousedown="rmc(event)" library="img" name="myImage.png" class="RMC"/>
        <p:remoteCommand name="rightMouseClick" action="#{backingBean.method}" update="myImage"/>
</h:form>
    <script>
        $(document).on("mousedown", ".RMC", function () {
            $(".RMC").each(function () {
                this.oncontextmenu = function () {
                    return false;
                };
            })

            $(".RMC").mousedown(function (e) {
                if (e.button == 2) {
                    rightMouseClick();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        });

        function rmc(e) {
            this.oncontextmenu = function () {
                return false;
            };

            if (e.button == 2) {
                rightMouseClick();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

It will disable right mouse menu on images with class `RMC` and invoke method from backing bean. If you don't want to disable the menu just remove `.each()` part.

EDIT:
After updating DOM element, it loses events given during `$(document).ready()` so you have to add `onmousedown` event directly in component.

EDIT2:
Changed `$(document).ready()`, now works for elements with RMC class even after update.

Comment: Thanks. I just cannot seem to find the motivation to actually create answers like this. Always wonder why people cannot think of things like this themselves.

Comment: thanks @Geinmachi. Will that work only for action methods (as compared to actionListener)? I tried actionListener method (which returns void). However, it works only the first time, after the method returns, the right click function/method is not getting invoked in javascript or in the backing bean (I put console.log statements in the javascript code)

Comment: Why do you want actionListener?

Comment: The backing bean method was not getting invoked more than once. So I tried both action and actionListener and none of them are getting invoked. I even added process=@this on the remoteCommand, but both the JS function and the backing bean method are getting invoked only once. Also, even though the method is getting invoked the first time, I am still seeing the context menu.

Comment: It invokes for me every time, maybe post whole `<h:form>`

Comment: I think I pinpointed the issue, I have an update attribute on the remoteCommand tag - <p:remoteCommand name="rightMouseClick" action="#{guideBean.updateCount}" process="@this :createGuideForm:panel"  update="image" />. If I remove the update attribute, it works fine. Does it work for you if you have the update attribute to update only a part of the page?

Comment: @user972391 Where exactly did you say that you update your image in `<p:remoteComand>`? I edited my answer and now it should work.

Comment: thank you, you are right, it was losing events after updating DOM. Your edit fixes it. Now I deleted the onready function completely from the Javascript (as it is redundant for the first time).

Comment: Edited my answer again if you are interested in class event, now works even after update.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple…  Break down your problem. Think html first. You should simply add a right click via jquery and use a `p:remoteCommand` to call a backingbean