# Using jQuery how to get right click coordinates on the target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-click

Is there any way to find the co-ordinates of a right click event on a div element as I have to set context menu based on the position of click.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's best to make an attempt, write some code, and return if you're unsure of how to progress/there are errors you don't understand. On principle, SO generally won't write your code for you from scratch

Comment: x and y from the whole page? than use the clientX and clientY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('div').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    console.log(e.pageX);
    console.log(e.pageY);
});
```

And for whole page:

```
$('div').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    console.log(e.clientX);
    console.log(e.clientY);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shree/awf5u2xx/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $(document).on('mousedown', '#TargetElementId', function (e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { // Right mouse button clicked

      return {e.pageX, e.pageY} //return co-ordinates
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```

From [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/706728/4281154) to find right mouse button clicked