# make selections by right clicking and dragging in full calender

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

How can I make the selections by Right Clicking and Dragging in fullcalendar? from the doc, we can left click and drag for select the time slot and create the event if selectable is set to true. But how can we enable right click for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind event to right mouse click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve