# Button should be select on right click

Tags: html, css

I have `button` that has following effect by `CSS`

```css
button{
  margin:10rem ;
  width:10rem
}
button#package_select:focus
{
    border: 1px solid #fbd03c    !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    outline:none;
    
}
```

```html
<center>
  <button id ="package_select">select</button>
 </center>
```

It is working fine. But Here my question is

The Button is selecting if you Right click and left click also. I want to select the button only when the user clicked on Right click on the Mouse.

How we can achieve this through Pure `CSS`?

Comment: This cannot be achieved with CSS. Also please note that the `center` tag has long been removed from current HTML. https://benohead.com/html5-removed-elements-tags-and-attributes/

Comment: I don't think this can be done purely in `css`. You can also fire the effect by tabbing until you reach the button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by CSS since you can not catch the contextmenu of the click even. So you need to use JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("package_select").addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
   this.className += "select_button";
    console.log("Added Button");
    return false;
}, false);
```

```css
.select_button {
 border: 1px solid #fbd03c    !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;
 outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button id ="package_select">select</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To simulate the `focus` action you have to use 2 functions**

1. Use `event.which == 3` to know if you click on right side and `addClass` to `button` with the wanted style....
2. Use `window.addEventListener("click", function(event)` to remove the `focus`(means to remove the class you added)

```js
document.getElementById("package_select").onmousedown = function(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        this.className += "select";
    }
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var elem=document.getElementsByClassName("select")[0];
  if(elem !=undefined)
     elem.className=""

});
```

```css
    button{
      margin:10rem ;
      width:10rem
    }
   .select
    {
        border: 1px solid #fbd03c!important;
        border-radius: 5px!important;
        outline:none;
        
    }
```

```html
<center>
      <button id ="package_select">select</button>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with pure css.
Need to help from javascript(but it will not guarantee, that it will work ok in all the devices).

Please check with the basic example code:

```
<script>
(function() {
  // The code to run on document ready;
  disable_rclick_on_btn();
})();

function disable_rclick_on_btn() {
  document.getElementById('package_select').addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}
</script>
```